# Lazy loading belongsTo

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a child and a parent model that are linked via `DS.belongsTo`.  In my `child/index` template I link to the parent:

```
{{linkTo "parent" parent}} go to parent {{/linkTo}}
```

Now here's my issue: Ember Data sideloads all of the parent models (even though I specified `async: true` in the `belongsTo` relationship) one by one. This seems to be caused by `linkTo` because when I remove that line this behavior stops.

How do I prevent ED beta 3 from doing this? The use case is that my child model is a partial model of the parent so this behavior defeats the point of my setup (and seems unnecessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @kinpin2k's answer would work, I found a better one: I just discovered that `{{link-to}}` accepts ids as arguments, too.

In my case I changed `parent: DS.belongsTo('parent')` to `parent_id: DS.attr('string')`. There was no need to change any of my back end since that's how Active Model Serializer returns it anyways. I then change my template to:

```
{{link-to "parent" parent_id}} go to parent {{/link-to}}
```

and everything works nicely because (as @kingpin2k nicely explained) Ember does not access the parent model anymore.

EDIT: Updated to reflect new syntax: {{linkTo}} is now {{link-to}}

Comment: It does indeed, glad you found a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's isn't Ember Data, it's Ember accessing the model.  Async means don't load it until someone tries to access it, using it in a link-to is considered using it.

You could add it to an action, and then transition to the route instead of using the link0to

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That was helpful, but I found a simpler solution (see my answer).